When packaging with maven I seem to have an issue with org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW
I am compiling and packaging my programme with maven and it compiles and package with out any errors, when I run my jar from the command line UI loads well, however when I press the play button I get an error:
"Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW
at gameGraphics.GraphicsDisplay.init(GraphicsDisplay.java:54).
I am using Eclipse as my IDE and have a maven project.
The UI is coded using Swing.
UI.png
I have made a class called GraphicsDisplay which creates my GLFW window using LWJGL:
GLFW window (GrapicksDisplay class)
the Graphics display class is called when I press the play button in the UI and runs on a separate thread.
So when I run my programme in eclipse it all works fine.... good
When I export my programme using Eclipse export and put my source folders with my runnable it all works fine.
When I do a maven clean, compile and package the UI works fine however when I press the play button I get the above error:
"Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW
at gameGraphics.GraphicsDisplay.init(GraphicsDisplay.java:54).
So here is my pom.xml:
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
4.0.0
<groupId>nhvdr</groupId>
<artifactId>javaSwingBuild_2D</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>javaSwingBuild_2D</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    <lwjgl.version>3.3.4</lwjgl.version>
    <joml.version>1.10.7</joml.version>
    <lwjgl3-awt.version>0.1.8</lwjgl3-awt.version>
    <steamworks4j.version>1.9.0</steamworks4j.version>
    <steamworks4j-server.version>1.9.0</steamworks4j-server.version>
    <joml-primitives.version>1.10.0</joml-primitives.version>
    <lwjgl.natives>natives-windows</lwjgl.natives>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengles</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengles</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joml</groupId>
        <artifactId>joml</artifactId>
        <version>${joml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjglx</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl3-awt</artifactId>
        <version>${lwjgl3-awt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.code-disaster.steamworks4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>steamworks4j</artifactId>
        <version>${steamworks4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.code-disaster.steamworks4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>steamworks4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${steamworks4j-server.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joml</groupId>
        <artifactId>joml-primitives</artifactId>
        <version>${joml-primitives.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>nhvdr.javaSwingBuild.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

What could I be missing?

I'm not familiar enough with Maven to give you an answer, but here's some related questions: the Maven-specific NoClassDefFoundError on Maven dependency and the more general NoClassDefFoundError in Java

Consider using [tag:jpackage]. The maven-dependency-plugin, suggested here, may be helpful.

You got your pom.xml file mostly correct. It's just failing to build a fat jar. You can see that Maven is producing a skinny jar when opening it with 7zip, since no LWJGL files are included in the archive.
Replace your plugins with these two to build a fat jar:
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>nhvdr.javaSwingBuild.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

When you build, two jars will be created. The one labeled [your_jar_name]-jar-with-dependencies.jar is the fat jar. This solution is based on this StackOverflow thread about building a fat jar with Maven.
Note that the fat jar produced will only be able to run on Windows machines, since you only selected the natives for windows-x64 on the LWJGL customize site. If you want your fat jar to run on every computer, on the LWJGL customize webiste, you have to:

Select "Maven" under the "Mode" category
Select all platforms you want to support under "Natives"
Download the new file and update your current pom.xml file accordingly.

You will not need to update anything under plugins after making this change.

Thank you I am currently working with it, however my resources are still not loading so have to find a way to load my resources.

@NicolasReyneke Can you provide more information about your current problem please? When you open the jar with 7zip, do you see any LWJGL-specific files? If you don't have enough space here, you can also edit your original question and let me know that you did so.

yes I have two files under my src/main/resources pics and resources. my window icon is working for swing however the paths for the shaders do not seem to be incorrect or not found so I am working on this: javaSwingBuild_2D-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\shaders\vertexShader.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

When working with resources and jars you have two options: 1. include them in the resources dir (which it seems like you are already doing) and use Object.class.getResourceAsStream(/path/from/resources/root) (more detail here). 2. Have your resources as separate files in your application's file structure and read them as you normally would. If you don't do either of these two things it will say that the filepath is not found.

Thank you I have worked with this and for now just gone away from maven for a bit and using libraries directly. There seems to be an issue with STB from JLWGL that when you want to load images on runtime after packaging STB can not load the files so it is another issue. All other resources are loading fine now thank you. The LWJGL still not working on runtime when I use Maven however when I set up my libraries locally I seem to have no problem so that is why I moved away from Maven for now.
